# Is it possible to sum a expression column in access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a column in access I need to get the total of. When I try the below method in my query I get the error "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ID' as part of an aggregate function."

```
Expr1: Sum([Column1])
```

Edit my query:

```
SELECT tblTest.ID,Field1,Sum([Field1]) AS Expr1 From tblTest;
```

Comment: can you post your entire query?

Comment: You are getting the sum with respect to what?  If the entire table, then you can't have any other columns in the query (which row should it return, for example when you are summing multiple rows).  If with respect to a group, then you need to group by some columns and include *only* those grouped columns.

Comment: There is just one other colmn, very simple select qry

Comment: @user1342164 there might be one column, but it would be helpful to see your full query.

Comment: I just want the total of the column like you would do in excel? I dont mind if the total for the column appears in every row I just need that number some how

Comment: SELECT tblTest.ID,Field1,Sum([Field1]) AS Expr1 From tblTest;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question needs more details but I think you want this:

```
SELECT Sum(yourColumn)
FROM yourTable
```

Then if you need to you will have to add a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Sum(yourColumn)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY yourTable.Id
```

Based on your comment your query would be:

```
SELECT ID
    ,Field1
    ,Sum([Field1]) AS Expr1 
From tblTest
GROUP BY ID, Field1;
```

Comment: That seems to just give me the same row data its not adding the entire column? SELECT test.ID, Sum(test.[Field1]) AS [Sum]
FROM test
GROUP BY test.ID;